# Will blocks hold execution on the thread it is run on?

Tags: objective-c

If I had a block like so:

```
(void) ^contrivedExample = ^{//some expensive operation//};
```

And use it like so:

```
int test = 1;

contrivedExample()

test++;
```

Since incrementing test takes no time, will this only occur after my block has fully executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will hold execution.  The increment will occur only after your expensive block finishes executing.

If you need to brush up on your blocks, here's a good read on the matter:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Incrementing `test` will occur after the block has completely finished executing.  Blocks aren't asynchronous in and of themselves, although they are often used by APIs that **are** asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can even have it run on a different thread by calling either `dispatch_sync` or `dispatch_async`.

`dispatch_sync` means the block runs on a different thread, while the current thread waits for the block to complete.

`dispatch_async` sends the block to another thread and the current thread continues.